# Impossible linker error

Tags: gcc, linker, virtual, linker-errors, vtable

I have a library, `libfoo` which is made of the following files:

#### `base.hpp`

```
#ifndef BASE_HPP
#define BASE_HPP

class base
{
        public:

        virtual ~base();

        virtual void foo() = 0;
};

inline base::~base() {}

#endif /* BASE_HPP */
```

#### `derived.hpp`

```
#ifndef DERIVED_HPP
#define DERIVED_HPP

#include "base.hpp"

class derived : public base
{
        public:

        void foo();
};

#endif /* DERIVED_HPP */
```

#### base.cpp

```
#include "base.hpp"
```

#### derived.cpp

```
#include "derived.hpp"

void derived::foo()
{
}
```

When I try to use it in a simple program:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <derived.hpp>

int main()
{
        derived d;

        return 0;
}
```

I get the following linker error:

```
scons -Q -C libfoo
scons: Entering directory `/home/ereon/git_work/box/libfoo'
g++ -o base.os -c -fPIC base.cpp
g++ -o derived.os -c -fPIC derived.cpp
g++ -o libfoo.so -shared base.os derived.os
scons -Q -C bar
scons: Entering directory `/home/ereon/git_work/box/bar'
g++ -o main.o -c -I/home/ereon/git_work/box/libfoo main.cpp
g++ -o bar main.o
main.o: In function `derived::derived()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN7derivedC2Ev[_ZN7derivedC5Ev]+0x1f): undefined reference to `vtable for derived'
main.o: In function `derived::~derived()':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN7derivedD2Ev[_ZN7derivedD5Ev]+0x13): undefined reference to `vtable for derived'
collect2: ld returned 1
scons: *** [bar] Error 1
make: *** [all] Erreur 2
```

Now the funny thing is that I only get this error on my Debian Wheezy `x86_64` machines (I tried on two different computers).

I also tried on a Debian Wheezy `amd64` with the **exact same compiler version**: `gcc (Debian 4.6.1-4) 4.6.1` and there it links fine.

What could be wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You neglected to include the shared lib in the linker inputs when linking?

Comment: Damn me. Obviously yes. I actually get this exact error message in a bigger (way more complex project) and tried to reproduce the buggy behavior in a simpler sample. It works fine after I added the missing library. I guess I will have to keep looking for the real problem in my complex library... Anyway, this question is solved. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can't link just `main.o` without `derived.o` as well. Unless the first virtual function (or first function for a class with no direction virtual functions) is linked in, the `vtable` won't be linked in.